# send video files to multiple display devices,wireless,over a 40 km radius,without the use of Internet if possible

Tags: wireless-networking

I would like to set up a system where i can send video files to multiple display devices,wireless,over a 40 km radius,without the use of Internet if possible...
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated since am new to this.

Please outline all the hardware & software needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out Ubiquiti Networks' Powerbeam AC antennas and receivers. As well as 'Long Distance Wifi by Linustechtips' on YouTube. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Boitshepo Your welcome. Mind upvoting for me? :D

Comment: Upvoted. checked out the video.quite good for sharing Internet.how can i use it to solve my problem?.....Basically i want to set up a number of display devices in taxis,buses,shopping malls,restaurants e.t.c then i want to be able to send video adds from my office to those devices with minimal or no costs at all around that range.am looking to cover a small town.the idea is to offer advertising services to small business who cant afford television.

Comment: Wow...then that gets really hard...I thought it was only an office to office thing...sorry I don't know further :(

Comment: In a way am glad to hear you say that,never thought ti would be easy.but am sure there should be a way.thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Boitshepo your welcome. Happy to help.